# Visit of homepage: redirected to sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, url-routing

Help!

When I visit my Wordpress website [www.de-sleutelbloem.nl](http://www.de-sleutelbloem.nl), I am redirected to stichting.de-sleutelbloem.nl.
That doesn't happen when I go to [www.de-sleutelbloem.nl/wat-doen-wij](http://www.de-sleutelbloem.nl/wat-doen-wij).
(Visiting [www.de-sleutelbloem.nl/index.php](http://www.de-sleutelbloem.nl/index.php) also redirects to stichting.de-sleutelbloem.nl.) There seems to be nothing wrong with stichting.de-sleuelbloem.nl.
What causes this behavior?
Did I accidentally delete or overwrite a file in the root?

It seems to work fine in Microsoft Edge, but not in Chrome and Firefox.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the problem has been solved. wp-config.php was overwritten and the problem still persisted.
But clearing the cache and history etc. solved the problem.